# Time dimension does not update in SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I had the problem with a Time dimension, which prevented my Cubes to be processed since it did not create weeks for 2016 as shown in the image below:

[image]

I figured out the source of the problem which occured from following configuration of the dimension:

[image]

I modified CalenderEndDate to "31-12-2016" and performed a "Full Process" of the dimension, but it still does not add the weeks for 2016. The last added week is still Week 53 in 2015. How do I add the new weeks in the dimension ?.